# Can we black hole the "errors" tag?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

It's worthless, IMO. Can we get it black holed, or at least discuss the possibility?

Comment: "errors" seems to be a uniquely useless tag (arguably worse than [tag:apache]) -- In furtherance of this goal I've updated the tag wiki/excerpt to ask people not to use [tag:errors] and instead describe the error message in the body of their question.

Comment: Only a handful of questions tagged [errors].  Perhaps retagging those so the tag goes away "voluntarily" would be enough, without blacklisting the tag?

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff I think that it's already been manually retagged. It's the kind of tag that people will recreate.

Answer (score 10):

[Yes we can! http://i43.tower.com/images/mm106974005/bob-builder-yes-we-can-dvd-cover-art.jpg](http://i43.tower.com/images/mm106974005/bob-builder-yes-we-can-dvd-cover-art.jpg)

Answer (score 10):

Agreed - errors and many of its friends (like [error-message](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/error-message)) need to die...

[image: [ERROR] IS TOTALLY UNHELPFUL]

Comment: I would up vote this, but you didn't provide a picture. Care to try again?

Comment: Pics or go home!

Comment: You are right - I apologize for my grievous error

Comment: Up vote status: granted

Answer (score 8):

[image]